# How to use AVCapturePhotoOutput

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, swift3

I have been working on using a custom camera, and I recently upgraded to Xcode 8 beta along with Swift 3. I originally had this:

```
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
```

However, I am now getting the warning:

> 'AVCaptureStillImageOutput' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use AVCapturePhotoOutput instead

As this is fairly new, I have not seen much information on this. Here is my current code:

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

func clickPicture() {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        videoConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData!)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1, orientation: .right)

            }

        })

    }

}
```

I have tried to look at `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`, but I am not quite sure how to use it. Does anybody know how to use this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to see WWDC 2016 session 511 video..

Comment: Ohk! So I will watch the video, and will post an answer if I can. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/reference/AVFoundation/AVCapturePhotoOutput) might help too.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Updated to Swift 4**
Hi it's really easy to use `AVCapturePhotoOutput`.

You need the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` which returns the  `CMSampleBuffer`.

You can get as well a preview image if you tell the `AVCapturePhotoSettings` the previewFormat

```
    class CameraCaptureOutput: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

        let cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

        func capturePhoto() {

          let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
          let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
          let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                               kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                               kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
          settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
          self.cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

        }

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {                        
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
              print("image: \(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size)") // Your Image
            }   
        }
    }
```

For more information visit https://developer.apple.com/reference/AVFoundation/AVCapturePhotoOutput

Note: You have to add the `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to the `AVCaptureSession` before taking the picture. So something like: `session.addOutput(output)`, and then: `output.capturePhoto(with:settings, delegate:self)` Thanks @BigHeadCreations

Comment: Gives error: "[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] No active and enabled video connection". Could you please provide full example for iOS 10 / Swift 3.

Comment: @TuomasLaatikainen you're likely need to set capture session preset to AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

Comment: I have watched the video, surfed the entire web, re-written code, changed iPhones and cannot resolve the exception "No active and enabled video connection."  The Apple doc is classically vague and void of details.  Help!  Is there a working project to share??

Comment: @TuomasLaatikainen did you figure out what the problem was for you? Having the same issue

Comment: @mobibob did you ever get an answer about what you could do for this? Same issue

Comment: What if I want to capture JPG?

Comment: @TuomasLaatikainen you have to add the `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to the `AVCaptureSession` **before** taking the picture. So something like: `session.addOutput(output)`, and then: `output.capturePhoto(with:settings, delegate:self)`

Answer (score 45):

There is my full implementation

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

var captureSesssion : AVCaptureSession!
var cameraOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

@IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
        if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSesssion.addInput(input)
            if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
                previewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                captureSesssion.startRunning()
            }
        } else {
            print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
        }
    } else {
        print("some problem here")
    }
}

// Take picture button
@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [
         kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
    ]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}

// callBack from take picture
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
        let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
        let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
        print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
        let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

        self.capturedImage.image = image
    } else {
        print("some error here")
    }
}

// This method you can use somewhere you need to know camera permission   state
func askPermission() {
    print("here")
    let cameraPermissionStatus =  AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    switch cameraPermissionStatus {
    case .authorized:
        print("Already Authorized")
    case .denied:
        print("denied")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry :(" , message: "But  could you please grant permission for camera within device settings",  preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel,  handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case .restricted:
        print("restricted")
    default:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: {
            [weak self]
            (granted :Bool) -> Void in

            if granted == true {
                // User granted
                print("User granted")
 DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            //Do smth that you need in main thread   
            } 
            }
            else {
                // User Rejected
                print("User Rejected")

DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WHY?" , message:  "Camera it is the main feature of our application", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(action)
                self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)  
            } 
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How did you set flashMode to it?

Comment: Working on iOS 10.0.2. For turn on flash `settings.flashMode = .on`

Comment: Why UIImageOrientation.right ? Then it's a wrong orientation on iPad.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 18):

In iOS 11 `"photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {}" is deprecated`.

Use following method:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
    if let data = imageData, let img = UIImage(data: data) {
        print(img)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I took **@Aleksey Timoshchenko's** excellent answer and updated it to `Swift 4.x`.

Note that for my use-case I allow the user to take multiple photos which is why I save them in the `images` array.

Note that you need to wire up the `@IBAction takePhoto` method via your `storyboard` or in code. In my case, I use a `storyboard`.

As of `iOS 11`, the `AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation` that is used in **@Aleksey Timoshchenko's** answer is deprecated.

### Swift 4.x

```
class CameraVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

    var images = [UIImage]()

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var cameraOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        startCamera()
    }

    func startCamera() {
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
           let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
            if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                if (captureSession.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                    captureSession.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                    previewLayer.frame = cameraView.bounds
                    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    captureSession.startRunning()
                }
            } else {
                print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
            }
        } else {
            print("some problem here")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
        let previewFormat = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
        ]
        settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
        cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)   
    }
}

extension CameraVC : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("error occured : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let dataImage = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.right)

            /**
               save image in array / do whatever you want to do with the image here
            */
            self.images.append(image)

        } else {
            print("some error here")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It focus in the core aspects to make it work !!!

Comment: Great answer. But note that `fileDataRepresentation()` requires iOS11

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me. Works even in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I found this project in GitHub that helped me understand the initialization of the device and capture-session.

[AVCapturePhotoOutput_test by inoue0426](https://github.com/inoue0426/AVCapturePhotoOutput_test)

Answer (score 2):

The `capture` delegate function has been changed to `photoOutput`. Here's the updated function for Swift 4.

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {            
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print("image: \(String(describing: UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size))") // Your Image
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact same answer as the one given by [@productioncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53998618/14267427) but I had to change the `startCamera()` to under `viewDidLoad()` instead of `viewDidAppear()`.