# Unable to use AVCapturePhotoOutput to capture photo swift + xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, avfoundation

I am working on a custom camera app and the tutorial uses AVCaptureStillImageOutput, which is deprecated for ios 10. I have set up the camera and am now stuck on how to take the photo

Here is my full view where i have the camera

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var cameraPos = "back"

class View3: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var clickButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!
var session: AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    clickButton.center.x = cameraView.bounds.width/2
    loadCamera()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
 }

@IBAction func clickCapture(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
       // This is where I need help 
        }
}

@IBAction func changeDevice(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if cameraPos == "back"
    {cameraPos = "front"}

    else
    {cameraPos = "back"}


    loadCamera()
}

func loadCamera()
{
    session?.stopRunning()
    videoPreviewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front)

    if cameraPos == "back"
    {
        backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)
    }

    var error: NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }

    if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {
        session!.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            session!.startRunning()

        }        }
}
}
```

This is where i need help

```
@IBAction func clickCapture(_ sender: UIButton) {

if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
   // This is where I need help 
    }
}
```

I have gone through the answer here [How to use AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869963/how-to-use-avcapturephotooutput)
but i do not understand how to incorporate that code in this code, as it involves declaring a new class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there.

## For Output as `AVCapturePhotoOutput`

Check out `AVCapturePhotoOutput` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput) for more help.

These are the steps to capture a photo.

1. Create an `AVCapturePhotoOutput` object. Use its properties to
   determine supported capture settings and to enable certain features
   (for example, whether to capture Live Photos).
2. Create and configure an `AVCapturePhotoSettings` object to choose
   features and settings for a specific capture (for example, whether
   to enable image stabilization or flash).
3. Capture an image by passing your photo settings object to the
   `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` method along with a delegate object
   implementing the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` protocol. The photo
   capture output then calls your delegate to notify you of significant
   events during the capture process.

have this below code on your `clickCapture` method and don't forgot to confirm and implement to delegate in your class.

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                             kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                             kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160,
                             ]
settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
self.cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

---

## For Output as `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`

if you intend to snap a photo from video connection. you can follow the below steps.

**Step 1: Get the connection**

```
if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
  // ...
  // Code for photo capture goes here...
}
```

**Step 2: Capture the photo**

- Call the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` function on
  the `stillImageOutput`.
- The `sampleBuffer` represents the data that is captured.

---

```
stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
  // ...
  // Process the image data (sampleBuffer) here to get an image file we can put in our captureImageView
})
```

**Step 3: Process the Image Data**

- We will need to to take a few steps to process the image data found in sampleBuffer in order to end up with a UIImage that we can insert into our captureImageView and easily use elsewhere in our app.

---

```
if sampleBuffer != nil {
  let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
  let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
  let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
  let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
  // ...
  // Add the image to captureImageView here...
}
```

**Step 4: Save the image**

Based on your need either save the image to photos gallery or show that in a image view

---

For more details check out [Create custom camera view guide](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Camera-View) under *Snap a Photo*

Comment: the captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection function is not a member of AVCapturePhotoOutput, it is of AVCaptureStillImageOutput

Comment: `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` is to take photo from a video with custom camera. and `AVCapturePhotoOutput` is used to take picture directly

Comment: but having stillImageOutput as an object of AVCapturePhotoOutput, and then stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
 gives error

Comment: you have to choose the image output ..it can be either `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` or `AVCapturePhotoOutput ` or you can have two outputs as well. then follow the steps mentioned above.

Comment: it will give error for sure as it is member of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` and not `AVCapturePhotoOutput`. If you want to use `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` you have to follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput)..Remember there is two ways here.. Dont get confused

Comment: I want to use AVCapturePhotoOutput and not AVCaptureStillImageOutput

Comment: then follow above first step which confirms to delegate `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` .. i edited the answer.