# Improve speed of captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Is there any way I could improve the speed of [captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturestillimageoutput/1387374-capturestillimageasynchronouslyf) ?

I've tried to simply focus on outputted frames, like so: [captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput?language=objc), but that doesn't really solve the problem. Besides, I can't get the same resolution from that delegation method as I could with the `captureAsync` method above.

So my question is, is there any way I could improve the return speed of `captureAsync`? Right now I'm averaging about ~0.5 seconds each on an iPhone 7.

Maybe disabling HDR, etc. ? If anyone has any input, I'd be forever thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have already know,`captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:`
 is deprecated from iOS 10.

As per apple documentation

> The AVCaptureStillImageOutput class is deprecated in iOS 10.0 and does
>   not support newer camera capture features such as RAW image output,
>   Live Photos, or wide-gamut color. In iOS 10.0 and later, use the
>   AVCapturePhotoOutput class instead. (The AVCaptureStillImageOutput
>   class remains supported in macOS 10.12.)

Since you are targeting iPhone 7 i would suggest to use `AVCapturePhotoOutput` and its delegate `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`

For more info chceck out my previous SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924915/capturing-still-image-with-avfoundation/41928999#41928999)

To increase the speed, AFAIK only way is to use `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`

- it gives you the frames which are processed by Capture Device.
- To ensure you get a high quality picture, you need to add correct AVCapturePhotoSettings and get high quality image data.

From my testing results for processing speed this method can process more then 20 frames per second for iPhone 6 and more then 50 frames per second on iPhone 7 and 7 plus (note it might be not exact result as my photo settings and image processing might be different then yours)

Comment: `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` seems to be the only option. Thanks @Bluewings