# AVCapturePhotoOutput jpegPhotoDataRepresentation access preview photo

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, avcaptureoutput

I see that iOS 10 introduces `AVCapturePhotoOutput` as the new class to deal with capturing photo's and has the ability to create a preview/thumbnail image alongside the main image by passing two buffers to the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` method `capture`.

This can then be represented as JPEG data through `jpegPhotoDataRepresentation`, however I'm intrigued and unable to find out how the preview image is stored then accessed. I'm guessing a `UIImageView` would automatically select either image dependant upon view bounds? How would you go about manually selecting either image?

```
let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)
captureImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Comment: Check the answer of this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869963/how-to-use-avcapturephotooutput

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the thumbnail is embedded in the header for the full size JPEG image. For more information, you can check out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format