# No type or protocol named 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use my Swift class into Objective-C code and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893793/8017437) answer to do so. However, after import `MyModule-Swift.h`, I'm getting compile error in `MyModule-Swift.h`:

> No type or protocol named 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'

Even though it contains `@import AVFoundation;` at the top. I'm clueless how to solve this. All I'm trying to do is to use one of the model class (written in Swift) in Objective-C.

Comment: Did you added protocol methods of AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869963/how-to-use-avcapturephotooutput

Comment: I've implemented `didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer` method in my VC

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've implemented my VC just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41723819/8017437)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using .**mm** file.

Use **.m** instead.