# No type or protocol named 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate' error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, objective-c++

I am trying to use Swift class in objective-c code. I already went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561770/no-type-or-protocol-named-avcapturephotocapturedelegate)

and I can't convert my `.mm` file to `.m` file as I am using react native's new architecture which requires `.mm` file

I am trying this out for react native's new architecture which requires .mm file. Check [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components) to learn more

My header file `RTNMyCamera.h`

```
#import <React/RCTViewComponentView.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface RTNMyCamera : RCTViewComponentView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

My `objective-c++` file `RTNMyCamera.mm`

```
#import "RTNMyCamera.h"

#import <react/renderer/components/RTNMyCameraSpecs/ComponentDescriptors.h>
#import <react/renderer/components/RTNMyCameraSpecs/EventEmitters.h>
#import <react/renderer/components/RTNMyCameraSpecs/Props.h>
#import <react/renderer/components/RTNMyCameraSpecs/RCTComponentViewHelpers.h>

#import "myapp-Swift.h"
#import "RCTFabric/React-RCTFabric-umbrella.h"

using namespace facebook::react;

@interface RTNMyCamera () <RCTRTNMyCameraViewProtocol>
@end

@implementation RTNMyCamera {
  UIView *_view;
  MyCamera *myCamera;
}

+ (ComponentDescriptorProvider)componentDescriptorProvider
{
  return concreteComponentDescriptorProvider<RTNMyCameraComponentDescriptor>();
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    static const auto defaultProps = std::make_shared<const RTNMyCameraProps>();
    _props = defaultProps;

    _view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myCamera = [[MyCamera alloc] initWithFrame:_view.bounds];
    [_view addSubview: myCamera];
    
    self.contentView = _view;
  }

  return self;
}

@end

Class<RCTComponentViewProtocol> RTNMyCameraCls(void)
{
  return RTNMyCamera.class;
}
```

My `swift` file `MyCamera`

```
@objcMembers
class MyCamera: UIView,AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
 //all of my business logic to capture photo
}
```

Entire swift code [here](https://gist.github.com/CodingWithNobody/8fb37230a34db2127442dd703506912e)

I get getting error saying `No type or protocol named 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'`

Here are few things I tried which did not work

1. I cannot convert `.mm` to `.m`
2. I tried creating `PrefixHeader.pch` and added `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` as well as `@protocol AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`
3. In `RTNMyCamera.h` I added `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`, `<AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate,AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>` and `@class MyCamera;`

[Here](https://github.com/CodingWithNobody/Deleteme) is sample repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import AVFoundation into your Swift file that uses AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, not your ObjC++. In MyCamera.swift you want `import AVFoundation`.

---

Looking at your repo, you created a prefix header, but didn't configure the project to use it.

```
// You will also need to set the Prefix Header build setting of one or more of your targets to reference this file.
```

The build setting you want is in the general pane:

[image: Apple Clang - Language section, Prefix Header]

It's called `GCC_PREFIX_HEADER`.

Comment: I have done that. I have to keep my post short and readable so I have not included my entire swift code. Check here if you like to see my entire swift code https://gist.github.com/CodingWithNobody/8fb37230a34db2127442dd703506912e

Comment: Your sample code doesn't reproduce this problem. It compiles file if EventEmitter references are commented out. I recommend building a tiny RN app that just imports this one thing, and build up from there until you reproduce the problem. Nothing you've described here seems to involve the C++, so it's unclear why that's your focus. Is there a C++ error you're not telling us about?

Comment: Here is a sample repo, please check https://github.com/CodingWithNobody/Deleteme. Please note it is using react native's new architecture. React native's new architecture internally uses C++ and the docs tells us to use objective-c++ and just using objective-c won't work for the new architecture

Comment: Thank you I have to set  precompile prefix header to yes and in prefix header => PrefixHeader.pch

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make sure the class implementing `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` extends `NSObject`.

Comment: Same issue..........