# AVCapturePhotoOutput has no member isCapturingStillImage

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, image-capture

Prior to `iOS 10` i was using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to capture an image, before I begin the capture I used to check for the boolean `isCapturingStillImage` which is clear what it does from its name, but `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` is deprecated with `iOS 10` and we have to use the new `AVCapturePhotoOutput` class, but couldn't find a way to check when it's currently capturing an image !! unfortunately `isCapturingStillImage` boolean is missing !!
how can I do this check with the new class `AVCapturePhotoOutput`? I couldn't find a clue in the docs about it.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869963/how-to-use-avcapturephotooutput)

Comment: What do you need this function for exactly? Perhaps there is another way to do this? You can use the photo capture delegate to say when it is finished

Comment: @LalKrishna there is no way in this link to check for isCapturingStillImage

Comment: @Spads I need it to check before capturing an image whether there is a previous capturing in progress or not

Comment: You can have multiple captures in progress, but if you don't want that you will need to store that state yourself and clear it from the photo capture delegate on completion. I can add details as an answer if you want.

Comment: @Spads I got the idea ... thank you so much .. no need for more details ..